# MySQL - ORDER BY one column if duplicate or reference doesn't exist in another

Tags: mysql

I have a table that (simplified) looks like this:

```
+----+--------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+--------+---------+
| ID | First name   | Last name | Street Address | Postal Address | Country | Spouse |
+----+--------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+---------+--------+
| 1  | Nancy        | Fuller    | Street 1       | City 1         | USA     | 4      |
| 2  | Andrew       | Davolio   | Way 2          | Town 2         | USA     | 0      |
| 3  | Janet        | Leverling | Blvd 3         | Village 3      | USA     | 0      |
| 4  | Steven       | Buchanan  | Street 1       | City 1         | USA     | 1      |
| 5  | Anne         | Dodsworth | Street 1       | City 1         | USA     | 0      |
+----+--------------+-----------+----------------+----------------+---------+--------+
```

As you can see, Nancy and Steven are married (the spouse column contains the ID of spouse, if any) and live together. Anne, Nancy's sister, also live with them (don't bother commenting the inconvenience).

Now I want to print this database. I want to order by last name, BUT on the print page I have two options:

- Group by address
- Group by spouse

So there are four scenarios:

**No grouping**
They are simply ordered by last name:

*Buchanan, Steven*

*Davolio, Andrew*

*Dodsworth, Anne*

*Fuller, Nancy*

*Leverling, Janet*

**Grouped by address**
When the first person of several with the same address is reached, all of them are printed (still sorted by last name in the group):

*Buchanan, Steven*
*Dodsworth, Anne*
*Fuller, Nancy*

*Davolio, Andrew*

*Leverling, Janet*

**Grouped by spouse**
When the first person in a couple is reached, both are printed:

*Buchanan, Steven*
*Fuller, Nancy*

*Dodsworth, Anne*

*Davolio, Andrew*

*Leverling, Janet*

**Grouped by address *and* spouse**
Combination of the above, spouse is prioritized (so Nancy appears before Anne since she's Steve's spouse).

*Buchanan, Steven*
*Fuller, Nancy*
*Dodsworth, Anne*

*Davolio, Andrew*

*Leverling, Janet*

And I really want them grouped, if that is possible, not just ordered after each other. As shown above I want space between not grouped persons, and no space between grouped persons. 
Is this possible using only MySQL, or do I have to use PHP as well?

*(I'm using PHP 5.5.16 and MySQL 5.5.39, PDO Objects)*

Comment: so you want to order by them being grouped and also return an empty row when they aren't grouped? what good is the space and why would you want that anyways (seems like a pointless request)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a bit unclear. I want the space on the printed paper, not in the db-result.

Comment: then why ask if you can do it all in MySQL? all that MySQL will be used for is getting a database result. if you want to print it out differently then do that in the application layer

Comment: Yeah, but how should the application layer know which ones are grouped? They just come in one long list. I somehow need to know which ones are grouped to add the spaces.

Comment: what query do you have so far? and what ordering do you want?

Comment: I don't have much of a query yet. I mean, `SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY lastname`. As stated, the ordering differs depending on the choices made. There are checkboxes for the two options on the before building the query.

Comment: do you want a result for every case?

Comment: When the user has made his choice, only the corresponding case is shown, but obviously I need to be prepared for all cases. I believe if I get an idea of how to build the last case (address and spouse) I can figure out the rest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65647/discussion-between-john-ruddell-and-punchlinern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this query I put the cast statements in the select part so that you can see how the data is getting laid out. you can migrate them to the ORDER BY if you want and only pull out the firstname, lastname.

### CASE: ordered by address and spouse

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN p1.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
    CASE WHEN p2.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    CONCAT(p.lastname, ', ', p.firstname)
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN people p1 ON p1.spouse = p.id
LEFT JOIN people p2 ON p2.streetaddress = p.streetaddress 
                   AND p.postaladdress = p2.postaladdress 
                   AND p2.id <> p.id
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2 DESC, 3 ASC;
```

### CASE: ordered by address

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN p2.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
    CONCAT(p.lastname, ', ', p.firstname)
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN people p2 
    ON p2.streetaddress = p.streetaddress 
   AND p.postaladdress = p2.postaladdress 
   AND p2.id <> p.id
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2 ASC;
```

### CASE: ordered by spouse

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CASE WHEN p1.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
    CONCAT(p.lastname, ', ', p.firstname)
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN people p1 ON p1.spouse = p.id
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2 ASC;
```

### CASE: ordered by nothing

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(p.lastname, ', ', p.firstname)
FROM people p;
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eabf0a/6)**

NOTE: if you keep the select as is with ordering then you can easily add spaces in the application layer... for instance if it pulls out a 1 then that means that the order is true for a spouse, address etc. if its a 0 then its false. so you can check for the value and if its a 0 start adding spaces

### EDIT:

to do an order by name ascending but to override it with another name that is a spouse or same address is not possible in MySQL. you can use the CASE statement to check in php if there is a spouse or not and change the ordering there.

Comment: I checked the demo, the sorting doesn't seem to be the way I want. Nancy should be after Steven (his last name starts on a lower letter). Same with Janet and Andrew.

Comment: @Punchlinern that is a simple fix one sec updating fiddle and answer

Comment: @Punchlinern does this all make sense to you?

Comment: Great! I'm trying to figure out how it's working. I'm not sure how the `CASE` helps, or how `ORDER BY 1`, `2` etc works.