# MySQL sub-query WHERE filtering out too much

Tags: mysql, subquery, where-clause

## Shorter version:

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f87c4/2)

Check the output-column `lives_together`. I want it to contain concatinated (comma-separated) IDs of the members who live at the same address as the current member, but isn't a parent or child to him/her.

So in the first row, John, I want the ID of Mary (only).
Not Josef since he is John's child, and not Victoria since she lives at another address (and she, too, is his child).

Right now I get nothing, somehow this is because of these rows in the query (in the third sub-query):

```
mem.id <> m3.parent1 AND
mem.id <> m3.parent2 AND
mem.parent1 <> m3.id AND
mem.parent2 <> m3.id AND
```

They are supposed to filter out all parents and children (which they do), but for some reason they also filter out other members as well (Mary in the example above).
**Just one** of these rows is enough to filter out Mary.
Another example is Mats and Gabriella, they should get eachother's IDs, but they don't.

(One column with all people `living_together` (including children) isn't enough, since I want to print the `living_together` persons before the children. This question is a development of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133068/mysql-order-by-one-column-if-duplicate-or-reference-doesnt-exist-in-another) I asked a while ago. One big difference in the result I want is that it should never group people with different last names.)

Why does this happen?

## Longer version

I have a table, `members`. A bit simplified it looks like this (you can see it in it's entirety in the SQLfiddle below):

```
+-------+------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| id    | first_name | last_name  | birthdate  | parent1 | parent2  | address  | phones    | mobiles   | emails        |
+-------+------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| 2490  | Mary       | Johansen   | 1964-01-24 | NULL    | NULL     | Street 1 | 1111      | 9999,8888 | mary@test.com |
| 2491  | John       | Johansen   | 1968-01-21 | NULL    | NULL     | Street 1 | 1111,3333 | 7777      | john@test.com |
| 2422  | Brad       | Johansen   | 1983-01-07 | 2491    | 2490     | Street 1 | 2222,3333 | 6666      | brad@test.com |
| 2493  | Victoria   | Andersen   | 1982-01-14 | 2490    | 2491     | Av. 2    | 4444      | 5555      | vic@text.com  |
+-------+------------+------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

Mary and John are married, with two kids; Josef and Victoria.
Victoria has moved out.

I want to print an address list, which groups those who live at the same address. So Mary, John and Josef should get grouped, but Victoria should get retrieved separately.
Children should be printed after spouses (and any other members living at that address), this is the reason for retrieving them separately.

*Here's how my database really looks, and my entire query:*

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f87c4/2
this is similar to actual data, the table contains about 400 rows.

So what I want is the `lives_together` output column to contain the `group_concat`inated IDs of the matched members. So I should get John's `id` in Mary's `lives_together` column, and the other way around. And not the children's ids.

I expect something similar to the following.
*Note that Brad is shown after John despite having both a lower id and a name starting on a letter earlier in the alphabet, this is because he is a child in the family. The children should be sorted by birthdate (you can see that column in the 
Also note that their phone numbers are added together with their last name, but their mobile numbers (and emails) are put with their names*

```
+----------------------------------------------------
| Andersen         Av 2       4444
|     Victoria                5555              vic@test.com
+----------------------------------------------------
| Johansen         Street 1   1111,2222,3333
|     John                    7777              john@test.com
|     Mary                    9999,8888         mary@test.com
|     Brad                    6666              brad@test.com
+----------------------------------------------------
```

This is, though, not what I expect from the query below, but my goal after some processing by PHP.

This is what I want from the query:

```
 +------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
 | id   | lname    | fname     | birthdate  | address  | phones    | mobiles   | emails        | parents   | children  | lives_together |
 +------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
 | 2490 | Johansen | Mary      | 1964-01-24 | Street 1 | 1111      | 9999,8888 | mary@test.com | NULL      | 2424      | 2491           |
 +------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
 | 2491 | Johansen | John      | 1968-01-21 | Street 1 | 1111,3333 | 7777      | john@test.com | NULL      | 2424      | 2490           |
 +------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
 | 2422 | Johansen | Brad      | 1983-01-07 | Street 1 | 2222,3333 | 6666      | brad@test.com | 2490,2491 | NULL      | NULL           |
 +------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
 | 2493 | Andersen | Victoria  | 1982-01-14 | Av. 2    | 4444      | 5555      | vic@test.com  | NULL      | NULL      | NULL           |
 +------+----------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+----------------+
```

Here's my query (also somewhat simplified):

```
SELECT 
    mem.id as id,
    mem.last_name as lname,
    mem.first_name as fname,
    mem.birthdate as birthdate,
    mem.address as address,
    mem.phones as phones,
    mem.mobiles as mobiles

    (SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(m1.id)
        FROM 
            members m1
        WHERE 
            (mem.parent1 = m1.id OR mem.parent2 = m1.id) AND
            LOWER(REPLACE(mem.last_name, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE(m1.last_name, ' ', '')) AND
            LOWER(REPLACE(mem.address, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE(m1.address, ' ', '')) AND
            mem.id <> m1.id
    ) as parents,

    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(m2.id)
        FROM 
            members m2
        WHERE 
            (mem.id = m2.parent1 OR mem.id = m2.parent2) AND
            LOWER(REPLACE(mem.last_name, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE(m2.last_name, ' ', '')) AND
            LOWER(REPLACE(mem.address, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE(m2.address, ' ', '')) AND
            mem.id <> m2.id 
    ) as children,

    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(m3.id)
        FROM 
            members m3
        WHERE 
            mem.id <> m3.parent1 AND
            mem.id <> m3.parent2 AND
            mem.parent1 <> m3.id AND
            mem.parent2 <> m3.id AND
            LOWER(REPLACE(mem.last_name, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE(m3.last_name, ' ', '')) AND
            LOWER(REPLACE(mem.address, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE(m3.address, ' ', '')) AND
            mem.id <> m3.id 
    ) as lives_together 

FROM 
    members mem 

ORDER BY
    mem.last_name ASC,
    mem.first_name ASC
```

When the query is at Mary, and goes through the third sub-query (`lives_together`) it should get John, but not Josef or Victoria.
Not Josef because of `mem.parent2 <> m3.id` and not Victoria because of `LOWER(REPLACE(mem.address, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE(m3.address, ' ', ''))`.
That works, but for some reason John isn't got either, I just get `NULL`.

I get both John, Josef and Victoria if I remove this part:

```
mem.id <> m3.parent1 AND
mem.id <> m3.parent2 AND
mem.parent1 <> m3.id AND
mem.parent2 <> m3.id AND
```

But when it's there I get none of them. I don't understand why that part filters out John as well. (Note that these lines aren't simplified at all.)
Just one of these for rows filters out John, but work as expected for Josef.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: The queries are the `fun part`. Setting up an environment to test them in is not. You need to make it easy for us to get to the 'fun part'?

Comment: I've added an SQLfiddle!

Answer (score 2):

> *I want to print an address list, which groups those who live at the same address. So Mary, John and Josef should get grouped, but Victoria should get retrieved separately.*

Perhaps you could look at this differently, by concentrating on the address? For example, this result:

```
|                                          Members | street_address |    postal_address | country |
|--------------------------------------------------|----------------|-------------------|---------|
|  John Andersson, Mary Andersson, Josef Andersson |       Street 1 |   61523 Stockholm |         |
|          Mats Anothername, Gabriella AnotherName |       Betmsv.4 | 641 93  Stockholm |         |
|                                   Marie Coolname |     Idrgatan 3 |  641 33 Stockholm |         |
|                                   Sofie Coolname |     Torvgen 12 | 641 53  Stockholm |         |
|                                 Victoria Johnson |       Avenue 3 |   61222 Stockholm |         |
```

Is produced by this query:

```
SELECT
      group_concat(DISTINCT concat( ' ',`first_name`, ' ',`last_name`)) as `Members`
    , mem.`street_address`
    , mem.`postal_address`
    , mem.`country`
FROM `members` as mem
WHERE `member_type` = 1
GROUP BY
      mem.`street_address`
    , mem.`postal_address`
    , mem.`country`
ORDER BY
      max(`last_name`)
    , `Members`
;
```

& with an **example** of using ORDER BY in the  GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT
      group_concat(DISTINCT concat( ' ',`first_name`, ' ',`last_name`)
                   ORDER BY
                          case when `parent1` IS NULL and `parent2` IS NULL then 1 else 2 end
                        , `birth_date` ASC
                  ) as `Members`
    , mem.`street_address`
    , mem.`postal_address`
    , mem.`country`
FROM `members` as mem
WHERE `member_type` = 1
GROUP BY
      mem.`street_address`
    , mem.`postal_address`
    , mem.`country`
ORDER BY
      max(`last_name`)
    , `Members`
;
```

Comment: The thing is that I want it to display children after the parents. I've tried to make that clearer in the question. I noted that your query actually produces a result like this, but if I'm not mistaken that is only luck in this case?

Comment: so add an ORDER BY in the GROUP_CONCAT, see amended answer for an **example**

Comment: This almost does it! I'm missing one thing though; check the updated table and the expected output, the notes in italic above the output. 
(I realize now that you needed this information to start with, but I was so focused on the `living_together`, so I didn't really think to include it.)
And one question: The `max(last_name)` part makes it order all the addresses by the members' last names, right?

Comment: (1) yes, that in for the final order, by name. (2) **(I realize now that you needed this information to start with** please remember this for your next question. by focusing on living_together you were limiting the solution options, and that is why knowing what the expected result is so important  - it allows us to dream up possible solutions. (Supply of relevant sample data is also important of course).

Comment: My approach is aimed at your mailing labels. It doesn't present the data in a hierarchy (row by row with indents). The "expected result" as I see it now cannot be met by my suggested simple query. You can of course also concatenate the phone numbers, just use the same approach as for the names. I don't know if this is adequate but I have at least helped you state your question more completely.

Comment: I tried making it even more clear what result I'm expecting. The indentation was mostly to visualize that it was a group, and only how I wanted it after some processing in PHP, etc.
I've added a table structure of what I want. Your solution, with concatenated phone numbers as well, could definitely work. 
A solution giving the result I've added to my question would be preferable, though, since it wouldn't require me to recode my PHP.
Either way I'm grateful for your help in clarifying my question!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are seeking, I figured that you want one record for each address and for each address list anyone else who lives at that address.

```
SELECT distinct 
    mem.id as id,
    mem.last_name as lname ,
    mem.first_name as fname,
    mem.birth_date as birthdate,
    mem.phone_number as phone,
    mem.mobile_number as mobile,
    mem.email_address as email,
    mem.co_address as co,
    mem.street_address as street,
    mem.postal_address as postal,
    mem.country as country,
    (SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(m3.id)
        FROM 
            members m3
        WHERE 
            LOWER(REPLACE(mem.last_name, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE(m3.last_name, ' ', '')) AND
            LOWER(REPLACE(mem.street_address, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE(m3.street_address, ' ', '')) AND
            LOWER(REPLACE(mem.postal_address, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE(m3.postal_address, ' ', '')) AND
            LOWER(REPLACE(mem.country, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE(m3.country, ' ', '')) AND
            mem.id <> m3.id 
            AND m3.member_type = 1
    ) as lives_together
FROM 
    members mem

WHERE
    member_type = 1
group by co_address,street_address,postal_address,country
ORDER BY
    mem.last_name ASC,
    mem.first_name ASC,
    mem.birth_date DESC
```

Comment: I need to have children and `living_together` in different columns, as I've added to the question. Otherwise I can't sort it as I want.